# Secure way to store passwords for bash automation

Tags: bash, security

At my workplace remote workers are expected to use VPN, which requests username and password every time you launch it. Since this is pretty cumbersome, I googled up a way to pass credentials from the command line and made it into an alias in my `.zshrc`. I understand that this is bad for security, since any user can read that file. What's the proper way of going about it? Please keep in mind that I cannot use something like SSH keys.

Now that I've written this, I've had an idea: would it be enough to `chmod 600` my `.zshrc` file? Or maybe `chmod` a folder, store creds in separate files there and `cat` them into aprropriate places on the command line. Would that be fine?

Comment: Can rhe VPN read credentials from environment variables?

Comment: There are other risks - another user doing a "ps" may be able to see tje username and password.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no requirement for ~/.zshrc to be world-readable – you can `chmod 600`  it and all other configuration files if you want. Similarly, you could `chmod 700` any directory to make its contents inaccessible to others. (The changes can also be applied with `chmod go=` or `chmod go-rwx` if you want to do it recursively to both files and directories at the same time.)

(You could even configure pam_umask to set an "umask" of 077 for your logins, so that all new files will be 0600 rather than 0644.)

Though in single-user, personal computers it probably matters little, as most attacks would come either from offline disk access (bypassing the OS) or from malware that's already running under your own account (and therefore can read your files anyway).

In now-rare cases when one wants to keep ~/.zshrc world-readable (e.g. on a shared community server), the shell built-in `source` or `.` command can be used to load additional scripts (e.g. `source ~/.zshrc_private` or `. ~/.zaliases`) into the context of the main script; the separate file could then have its own permissions.

File permissions aside, it is common to keep passwords in a **password manager** such as `pass` – scripts and aliases can then use `--password="$(pass Apps/Foo)"` when needed. The password manager provides on-disk encryption for the stored passwords, in case you aren't using full-disk encryption yet, so it improves security also against offline access (whereas file permissions are only effective when going through the OS in the normal way).

(Some desktop environments (GNOME, KDE) have their own password managers; e.g. GNOME Keyring entries are encrypted using the system login password and can be retrieved using `$(secret-tool lookup ...)`.)